# Getting wrong Gps Location in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am using GPS to fetch location at 15 second interval in my android application. It is giving correct data but sometimes it fetches forward location and after that again fetches backward location. In result i am getting wrong track on google map.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little big vague...

The problem with GPS is that it is highly dependent on your whereabouts. Things such as tall buildings and sometimes even large trees can have a major impact on your GPS readings. Being inside a structure or outside is also another major factor which must be considered. Also, most of the time, the GPS will return different GPS co-ordinates even if you stay in the same place.

The average margin of error of a GPS usually varies between 5 and 50m. When you say 'forward' and 'backward' location, I am assuming that you mean that the GPS is returning a value for a position which is either ahead of you or behind you.

The fact that, as you say, the GPS most of the time works, leads me to suspect that the issue you are experiencing varies depending on your actual physical location, however, due to the vague nature of your question we can only speculate...

My suggestion is that you try this out in various places, maybe some with clear access to the sky, and another in a crowded area and you see how the GPS behaves.

Comment: @SB24: If this question somehow solved your issues, up vote it or mark it as the question answer. This will help others with your same problem and and motivate others to answer your future questions.

Comment: You are getting the question correctly. when i go on straight road with clear sky, i get a triangle on track of google map instead of straight line.

Comment: @SB24: If this answer is correct, please tick the green 'very good' mark that is on the upper left corner of the answer which has been provided.

Comment: You are getting the question correctly. when i go on straight road with clear sky, i get a triangle on track of google map instead of straight line.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same problem while testing my Google navigation app.

The wrong location from GPS receiver is due to the lack of signal reception from GPS Satellites to GPS receiver.

This is due to the position of your GPS receiver device and also depends on the quality of GPS receiver.